# Jest: How to mock redux-thunk api response?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, thunk

I am having hard time to mock api response in my thunk. Mock returns data undefined.

Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: {"payload": {"data": ["hey", "foo"], "resultValue": 0}, "type": "products/setProducts"}

Received
1
Object {
-   "payload": Object {
-     "data": Array [
-       "hey",
-       "foo",
-     ],
-     "resultValue": 0,
+   "meta": Object {
+     "arg": undefined,
+     "requestId": "xwidHSyGluO0zxXJgYNCs",
+     "requestStatus": "pending",
},
-   "type": "products/setProducts",
+   "payload": undefined,
+   "type": "products/getProducts/pending",
},
2
Object {
-   "payload": Object {
-     "data": Array [
-       "hey",
-       "foo",
-     ],
-     "resultValue": 0,
-   },
-   "type": "products/setProducts",
+   "payload": undefined,
+   "type": "products/setFetching",
},

API file object with methods

```
import { instance } from "./index";
import { ProductType } from "../types/ProductType";

export const productsApi = {
    requestProducts() {
        return instance.get<ProductType[]>('products')
            .then(response => response.data)
    },
}
```

THUNK

```
export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk<void, void>
("products/getProducts",
    async function (_, { dispatch }) {
        dispatch(setFetching())
        try {
            const response = await productsApi.requestProducts() `Here is problem with mocking, returns undefined`
            dispatch(setProducts(response))
        } catch {
            dispatch(setError('Some error has been occurred'))
        } finally {
            dispatch(setFetching())
        }
    });
```

TEST

```
import productsSlice, {
    getProducts,
    productsSelector,
    ProductsStateType,
    setError,
    setFetching,
    setProducts
} from "./productsSlice";
import { RootState } from "../redux-store";
import { productsApi } from "../../api/products-api";

jest.mock("../../api/products-api")

const productsApiMock = productsApi as jest.Mocked<typeof productsApi>;

const dispatchMock = jest.fn();
const getStateMock = jest.fn();

beforeEach(() => {
    dispatchMock.mockClear();
    getStateMock.mockClear();
    productsApiMock.requestProducts.mockClear();
});

const result = {
    resultValue:0,
    data: ['hey','foo']
}

productsApiMock.requestProducts.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(result));

describe("products reducer thunk", () => {
    it("getProducts thunk success ", async () => {
        const thunk = getProducts();
        thunk(dispatchMock, getStateMock, {});
        expect(dispatchMock).toBeCalledTimes(2);
        expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(setProducts(result));
    });
});
```

Comment: In your line `productsApiMock.requestProducts.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.response(result));` did you mean to write `Promise.resolve`? Because `.response` is not a known Promise method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, no idea why i put response. But still has same problem.

Comment: Are you sure the arguments for `thunk` match? `createAsyncThunk` has a different signature for the arguments of the function you pass. It's `args, thunkAPI` not `dispatch, getState` like for classic thunks.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is in your code, but I'd consider using a library like `redux-mock-store`, it makes testing thunks a bit easier. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575200/how-to-unit-test-this-redux-thunk). The general approach is to only mock the external dependencies of thunks (api client for example), not dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Moving the line with **.mockReturnValueOnce inside test callback** helps me.

```js
describe("products reducer thunk", () => {
    it("getProducts thunk success ", async () => {
        //Like that
        productsApiMock.requestProducts.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(result));
        const thunk = getProducts();
        thunk(dispatchMock, getStateMock, {});
        expect(dispatchMock).toBeCalledTimes(2);
        expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(setProducts(result));
    });
});
```